# How to calculate speed of a moving object in unity

Tags: unity, mathematics

Currently I am trying to calculate the speed of an object here is the below code snippet:

```
void Start ()
{
  StartCoroutine( CalcVelocity() );
}
  
IEnumerator CalcVelocity()
{
  while( Application.isPlaying )
  {
    // Position at frame start
    prevPos = transform.position;
    // Wait till it the end of the frame
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    // Calculate velocity: Velocity = DeltaPosition / DeltaTime
    currVel = (prevPos - transform.position) / Time.deltaTime;
    Debug.Log( currVel );
  }
}
```

I am not sure if it is the correct way to do this? Did it suppose to provide Meters per second speed?

Comment: Why use a coroutine for this and not just put that code in `Update`?

Comment: Seems to be correct, it should give you meter over seconds speed. What's the result? What kind of problem did you encounter with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the negation of the object's velocity (same speed, opposite direction).

This isn't any different in Unity than it is in all the rest of linear algebra. If you want a vector *from* A *to* B, that's B - A, not A - B.

So your code should read:

```
currVel = (transform.position - prevPos) / Time.deltaTime;
```

And of course

```
speed = currVel.magnitude;
```

The speed and velocity are measured in world units per second. So if you think of one unit in your game world as being one metre, then this is metres per second.

To ensure you get a valid speed on the first loop of this coroutine, you will need to ensure you start it *before* the script that moves the object — otherwise you may get a false zero for the first frame.

Comment: Difference vector's magnitude is the speed? I should run this code in update.

Comment: The magnitude of a velocity vector is a speed..The magnitude of a displacement vector is a distance.